# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError using Omniauth in Gitlab 13.5.3 with Laravel Passport - local dev on macOS with Docker

Tags: ruby, docker-compose, gitlab, omniauth, laravel-passport

At a bit of a loss right now where to look next to resolve this issue. Would anyone have a suggestion on what I might look at or try to get this working? Happy to supply more information if need be.

Overview:

- Local setup on macOS Catalina
- oauth (client) GitLab 13.6.2 running in Docker on port 10080
- GitLab is using omniauth 1.8
- oauth (server) Laravel 8 Passport running on macOS using Laravel Valet with Nginx
- Passport tested with local Laravel site and oauth flow works perfectly
- In Gitlab, using custom omniauth gem based on omniauth-gitlab 1.0.2 (https://github.com/linchus/omniauth-gitlab) for Single Sign On
- /omniauth-site/lib/omniauth/strategies/site.rb is

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Site < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2

      option :client_options, {
        site: 'http://testaccounts.test',
        authorize_url: '/oauth/authorize',
        token_url: '/oauth/token'
      }

      option :redirect_url

      uid { raw_info['id'].to_s }

      info do
        {
        email: raw_info['email'],
        name: raw_info['name'],
        nickname: raw_info['username'],
        image: raw_info['avatar_url']
        }
      end

      extra do
        { raw_info: raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/v3/user').parsed
      end

      private

      def callback_url
        options.redirect_url || (full_host + script_name + callback_path)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I've tried adding `.to_s.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?')` to each of the assignments email, name, nickname and image,  as well as to the uid.

The flow appears to be good from GitLab to my Laravel Passport site:

- On GitLab, click on Sign with  button
- Authorize or Cancel buttons, click on Authorize
- Return to GitLab with this URL: http://localhost:10080/users/auth/site/callback?code=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&state=1f35df7bd654ca9c7786f83c7d4aec797ba9871746f8d3bc
- Page says '500 Whoops, something went wrong on our end.'
- In GitLab, gitlab-workhorse log shows:

```
localhost:10080 127.0.0.1 - - [2020/12/23:01:38:13 +0530] "GET /users/auth/site/callback?code=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&state=1f35df7bd654ca9c7786f83c7d4aec797ba9871746f8d3bc HTTP/1.1" 500 2926 "http://localhost:10080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" 462
```

- In GitLab, production.log shows:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 112)
Started GET "/users/auth/site/callback?code=[FILTERED]&state=1f663e1c64bb8d7c359a627e52c109922e85d9aad356ccb0" for 172.20.0.1 at 2020-12-23 01:40:31 +0530

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

lib/gitlab/omniauth_logging/json_formatter.rb:9:in `call'
config/initializers_before_autoloader/100_patch_omniauth_oauth2.rb:11:in `callback_phase'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:234:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_null_bytes.rb:19:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:51:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:23:in `call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:49:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Answer (score 1):

This was one of those devious little oauth2 bugs that wasn't directly related to the callback. The client was already trying to get the user data after being successfully authorized. The /api/user route had a bug in it, which when fixed solved the above issue.

Based on something I read last night, it would seem that the error was a result of an HTML page being served up instead of the JSON data the client was expecting to see when it hit /api/user.